# Left menu doesn't work on mobile

Tags: angularjs, events, mobile, click

I have a left menu, and I have the a element:

```
<a ng-href="/{{i.url}}" ng-click="selectMenu(i,$event)"><i class="fa {{i.icon}}"></i><span>{{i.name}}</span></a>
```

Which will be with URL /dada (an example)

On computer all works good, but on mobile when I click on this element don't load the new page, I insert an alert in selectMenu to check if event listeners works, all works.
The a element remain focused after click.
I have SEO URL

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            template: '<b>dada</b>'
        }).
        otherwise({
            template: 'nu'
        }); 

    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true,requireBase: false});
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

}]);

RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^signup/?$ index.php?a=signup [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ index.php?a=login [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#!/$1 [L]
```

why doesn't work on mobile?

Comment: Maybe it isn't necessary a mobile problem, could just be a different browser problem. Try the mobile browser you're using on a desktop. If problem persists, it's the browser. If not, it's the mobile device. That at least is some progress to work with cause you don't want to be looking for a bug in the wrong place.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5307